# Pymongo : How to insert a document with a timestamp

Tags: python, mongodb, timestamp, pymongo

I would like to insert in a database a document with a timestamp and not a date.
If I insert the following document:

```
data = {'dt': dt.datetime.today().timestamp()}
```

The timestamp will be inserted as a double:
[image: Double example]

**What I would like is to have this type of data:**

[image: mongo timestamp example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Mongo does have a [timestamp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps) the docs do say the following:

> The BSON timestamp type is for internal MongoDB use. For most cases, in application development, you will want to use the BSON date type. See Date for more information.

Note that using timestamp type can also have issues with different driver support and issues regarding operator behaviour. pymongo uses [datetime.datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) objects for representing dates and times in MongoDB documents. And as you are already using `datetime` I would suggest just saving that as a `Date` not a timestamp.

If for whatever reason you insist on using `timestamp` type then you would need to use `bson.timestamp` type like so:`

```
from bson.timestamp import Timestamp
import datetime as dt
timestamp = Timestamp(int(dt.datetime.today().timestamp()), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw something extra in, the default `_id` field that is created automatically contains a "timestamp", and you can retrieve it using the `generation_time` property of the ObjectId object, without having to add your own field in e.g.:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

db.mycollection.insert_one({'a': 1})
record = db.mycollection.find_one({'a': 1})
print(record.get('_id').generation_time)
```

prints:

```
2021-03-14 17:08:51+00:00
```